# Align label to centre and left positions in DIV

Tags: css, html

I have a DIV like this:

```
    <div id="mydiv">
        <label id="orderName" style="align:center;">Order Name</label>
        <label id="orderNo" style="align:left;">Order No</label>  
    </div>
```

I am trying to:
- align OrderName horizontally and vertically center of the div. 
- align OrderNo horizontally left of the div (and vertically centred).

How can i do that?

```
    ----------------------------------
   |                                 |
   | OrderNo     OrderName           |
   |                                 |
    ----------------------------------
```

Comment: `align` is not a CSS property. Use `text-align` instead. For vertical alignment use `line-height` property.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Following css will give your expected result:

```css
div {
    text-align: center;
}
#orderName {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
#orderNo {
    float: left;
}
```

```html
 <div id="mydiv">
        <label id="orderName" >Order Name</label>
        <label id="orderNo">Order No</label>  
    </div>
```

**Solution 2:**

Other way using `display:flex`. Here i have added `height` and `border` to display vertical center.

And give `margin:0 auto;` to center.

```css
div {
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
    height: 40px;
    border: 1px solid;
}


#orderName {
    order: 2;
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="mydiv">
        <label id="orderName" >Order Name</label>
        <label id="orderNo">Order No</label>  
    </div>
```

Comment: Ketan> Although vertical alignment works now - But  Order Name only starts from center position(50%) now, instead of being centered - horizontally.

Comment: > Yes that works, however the Order Name starts shifting to right, as Order No length changes (i.e if Order No is 3 digits vs 10 digits, i update OrderNo dynamically, but OrderName remains constant) - if there is an easy way to handle that pls let me know - even so thankyou so much.

Comment: @Jasper Yeah man it is moving because it is in center. Give both label width `50%`

Answer (score 0):

name

Align the label and text field -

```css
.search-box-container{

  display:flex;
  width:60%
  background: black;
  margin:0 auto;
  font-size:25px;
}

.label{
  margin:auto;
}

input[type=text]{
  height:20px;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <body>
        <div class="search-box-container">
            <label for="" class="label">Name</label>
            <input type="text" class="searchbox"/>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```